# How to wrapAll an ELEMENT from title by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, title, wrapall

Now I am playing with [PageTranstionCollection](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/)

And I want to wrapAll an ELEMENT with title="wrap pt-page1". After that by Magic jQuery script it goes to

```html
<div class='pt-page pt-page-2'>
<div title='wrap pt-page-2'> ELEMENT Blahblahblah</div>
```

So I tried to modificate my ClassTitleAdder:

```html
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
$("[title*='class']").addClass(function(){
return $(this).attr('title');}).removeClass('class').removeAttr('title');
});</script>
```

TO:

```html
<script>//Враппит страницу полностью

$("[title*='wrap']").wrapAll(  (function(){
$(this).text('"<div class='pt-page');
return $(this).attr('title');
$(this).text('' />"'));}).removeAttr('title');</script>
```

Yes, I know it is very foolish for me, but can you help me? Maybe You have another Right solution?

Thanks. I hope you understood my question.

Some specific example for more details:

I have an element with title="wrap pt-page-1", another element with title="wrap **pt-page-2**" and so on. Script should do find elements with [title*='wrap'] after that wrapAll it and in future div will have class="pt-page **pt-page-2** (or pt-page-1)". SO **pt-page-2** must return from title (it is second word after wrap).

Comment: May I ask what is the original DOM , and what expected result do you want?

Comment: For example: I have an element with title="wrap pt-page-1", another element with title="wrap pt-page-2" and so on. Script should do find elements with [title*='wrap'] after that wrapAll it and in future div will have class="pt-page pt-page-2 (or pt-page-1)". SO pt-page-2 must return from title (it is second word after wrap).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanna achieve,I think your ELEMENT is something like this:

```
<div title="wrap pt-page1">blahblahblah</div>
```

and your expected output is:

```
<div class='pt-page pt-page-2'>
    <div title="wrap pt-page1">blahblahblah</div>
</div>
```

You may use the following script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[title="wrap pt-page1"]').wrapAll('<div class="pt-page pt-page-2"></div>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L9uf3rat/

**Updated version**
If you need to remove wrap in all element and then wrap your pt-page1 element, try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[title*="wrap"]').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).prop('title');
        title = title.replace('wrap','').trim();
        $(this).prop('title', title);        
    });

    $('div[title="pt-page1"]').wrapAll('<div class="pt-page pt-page-2"></div>');
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L9uf3rat/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my specific homework it doesn't work.

For example: I have an element with title="wrap pt-page-1", another element with title="wrap pt-page-2" and so on. Script should do find elements with [title*='wrap'] after that wrapAll it and in future div will have class="pt-page pt-page-2 (or pt-page-1)". SO pt-page-2 must return from title (it is second word after wrap).

Answer (score 0):

That is working script and what I need.

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[title*='wrap']").wrapAll(function() {
  return "<div class='pt-page " + $(this).attr('title') + "'></div>";
}).removeAttr('title')});
</script>
```

So may anybody know how to delete "wrap" class from every element?

Comment: is it possible to use "class" at the beginning rather than using title? because you can simply use removeClass in this case. Otherwise, I would suggest you to use regex selector plugin to select those element with "wrap" in their title attribute